# How do you fit AAM generated using Tim Cootes toolbox to a new image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I used the tools provided by Tim Cootes (http://www.isbe.man.ac.uk/~bim/software/am_tools_doc/). I have used annotated images to get an AAM (i.e. the .aam, .aamprops and .apm files have been generated).

How do I fit this AAM to a new image (non-annotated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think **you can't**. You have to provide a set of initial landmarks from which the search will start. That's because the program implements the ASM search only and does not include any face or eye detector to find a starting point for the algorithm.

Try Stephen Milborrow ASM/AAM software, [STASM](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/index.html). It has similar functionalities and, as I recall, includes face detection with two different algorithms for initialization. I learned a lot about ASM and AAM with it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion
unfortunately, I seem to get only the landmarks of ASM from the package. How do I get the texture information used by AAMs?